# laravel nested eager loading take and first function

Tags: php, laravel, orm

i have 3 Models

`VideoTopic`, `Video`, `VideoProgress`

that the relations are as below:

`VideoTopic:`

```php
/**
     * topic to videos Relation
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function videos() : \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Video", "topic_id");
    }
```

`Video:`

```php
/**
     * video to topic relation
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function topic() : \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\VideoTopic", "topic_i");
    }

    public function progresses() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\VideoProgress", "video_id");
    }
```

`VideoProgress:`

```php
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User", "user_id");
    }

    public function video() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Video", "video_id");
    }
```

I am Trying to fetch all of video topics with its videos and progresses for each video but i want to only get the last progress saved in the database so my code is as below:

```php
$topics = VideoTopic::first()->with(["videos" => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy("order");
            $query->with(["progresses" => function ($query) {
                $query->latest();
                $query->take(1);
            }]);
        }])->orderBy("order")->get();
```

but in the code above instead of giving one progress foreach video, it is giving only the last progress saved for one of videos ( not progresses for other videos ).
it just gives the last one.

but what i want is to get one progress foreach video if available.

i also tried the code below:

```php
$topics = VideoTopic::first()->with(["videos" => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy("order");
        }, "videos.progresses" => function ($query) {
                $query->latest();
                $query->take(1);
            }])->orderBy("order")->get();
```

also when i use first instead of take it does not work.

Comment: Try removing `take(1)` as latest is the only thing you want here.

Comment: What if you use `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` instead of `latest`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte latest just orders the results by created_at. i wanna get only one progress

Comment: @Matt tried but no changes. i think latest does that itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new relation using hasOne:

```
  public function lastProgresses() {
        return $this->hasOne("App\VideoProgress", "video_id")->latest();
    }
```

now use this relation instead of the old one:

```
$topics = VideoTopic::with(["videos" => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy("order");
        }, "videos.lastProgresses"])->orderBy("order")->first();
```